# "NoSuchMethodError : the getter 'length' was called on null" on Listview builder area

Tags: flutter

i want to ask about error that i got. so before someone claim this question is similar with others, maybe yes, but the others answer still cant solved my problem.

so, i have a problem with my code, the error show about 5 seconds, and then show the data list. then i search for solution and i found futurebuilder for the answer, but when i debug, the error still showed and it's permanent, not change to data list like before.
here is my code

> 

```
  List data;

  Future<String> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString('Json/indomodel.json');
    if(this.mounted){
    setState(() {
      data = json.decode(jsonText);
    });
    }

    //print(jsonText);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.loadJsonData();
    //loaddata();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var buildContext = (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
              height: 60.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                    alignLabelWithHint: true,
                    focusColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: "Ketik Kata",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    //labelText: "Bahasa Indonesia",
                    icon: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.search,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 15.0,
                    ),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                cursorColor: Colors.yellow,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: loadJsonData(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                    if(!snapshot.hasData)return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                      if(snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error ${snapshot.error}');
                      return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 0.3,
                        child: ListTile(
                     // leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.adjust),),
                      title: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[

                                SelectableText(
                                  data[index]['word'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.deepPurple.shade800),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "My Kamus",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                            Text(data[index]['trans'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 13.0),)
                          ],
                        ),
                    ),
                    );
                  },
                );
                    }
                  },
                )
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your `itemCount: snapshot.data.length,` with `itemCount: snapshot.data == null ? 0 : snapshot.data.length,`. That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because if there is no data, `snapshot.data` returns `null` and you are using it inside `ListView`, all you need to do is use this kind of approach:

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: loadJsonData(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){

   // if there is no data yet, show progress indicator. 
   if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());         

   // only show ListView if you have data
   return ListView.builder(...);
   }
)
```

I typed this code from phone, so there may be some basic syntax errors.

Comment: it stack on progress bar only. not showing the data. but thanks

Comment: That means your `loadJsonData` isn't returning any data. Please post code for that too.